# Looping using a for loop logic - Year

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm working on an iOS application. One of the function loops for the whole year from the current date and time.

```
for (int month_i = monthInt; month_i < 13; month_i++) {

       for (int i = dayInt  ; i <= monthRange.length ; i ++){


      }

}
```

I have retrieved the month number and range as follows:

```
    NSDateComponents *components = [calCurrent components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
    NSInteger year = [components year];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger day = [components day];

    NSNumber *monthNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: month];

    int monthInt = [monthNumber intValue];


    NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

        // Set your month here
    [comps setMonth:monthInt];

     monthRange = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                               inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                              forDate:[cal dateFromComponents:comps]];
```

This is my current execution. However I have a situation where I need to add public holidays from the Calendar application and avoid the dates that are marked as holidays on the calendar. 
I was thinking of using NSMutableDictionary where the object items are filtered with calendar items and set the key value as months name. Is there a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: why are you using nested loop to iterate? what is the reason/function behind this?

Comment: im loading info into database for every single day in the year

Comment: Please tell your full requirement so that we can come up with best possible solution

Comment: For every day in a month I create a table in the mySQL and this is looped until december 31st. Working on a event booking application.